# How to prevent multiple calls to get_queryset() in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my `views.py`, I have a custom `get_queryset()` that filters records on the user. When I update or create a specific record, I need information from the queryset to set some fields, so I end up with multiple calls to `get_queryset()`. If `get_queryset()` becomes more complex, my performance may decrease
a bit.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Gets the model instance (which calls get_queryset() by default)
    object = self.get_object()

    # Updates the object and passes the queryset to the update method.
    if object.update(json.loads(request.body), self.get_queryset()):
        return HttpResponse('Successfully updated object')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Error updating Object')
```

Is there anyway to store the queryset temporarily when I call `self.get_object`?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide the contents of `get_object()`. It's hard to determine what your question/problem is.

Comment: Have you verified that this is making multiple read queries via something like the Django Debug Toolbar?